# How to stop rerendering of child component when parent rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React. I am working on a project where I have a parent component. When I click on a link, it renders a modal. The modal is an another component.

Now If I make some changes in my parent component and click on the link, all the changes get reset.
 I know it's because parent component renders again .is there a way to stop this?

```js
export default class Positions extends DJSComponent {

    static propTypes = {
        positionGridData: PropTypes.array.isRequired
    };
    static defaultProps = {
        positionGridData: []
    };

    state = {
        showModalForAddNew: false,
    };
    
    closeAddNewModal = () => {
        this.setState( {
            showModalForAddNew: false
        });
    };

    openAddNewModal =() => {
        this.setState( {
            showModalForAddNew: true
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
        
              <div>
                  <Modal 
                    key="modal_addnew" 
                    modalTitle={'Add a New Row'}
                    show={this.state.showModalForAddNew} 
                    onModalClose = {this.closeAddNewModal} >

                     < AddNewModal /> 

                  <Modal>
                  
                  <Button 
                      onClick={this.openAddNewModal}
                  >
                      Add New
                  </Button>

                  <Grid
                      data={this.props.positionGridData}
                      style={{border:'1px solid silver'}}
                  />

            </div>
          );
    }
}
```

Basically, **Grid** Component is rendering a grid for me in the parent component. I don't want my Grid to get rendered again if I click on the **Add New** button . Like If I reorder my columns of the grid based on my preference and then when i click on Add New button, it's all gone as grid gets rendered again.

Edit 1:

[**My initial grid**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkEmu.png)

Now let's say I changed the columns like this.
[**Edited grid**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwZhN.png)

Now if I click on Add New button, my Grid comes back to Initial state as it gets rendered again which I don't want.

Comment: Edited my Question. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing style as the object here like this while rendering Grid Component:

```
style={{border:'1px solid silver'}}
```

It will always pass a new reference of the JSON object to Grid Component whenever your Positions Component renders. It would be better if you put style as a constant at the top of the file and you that constant here or you define the style using className.

Ex:

```
const gridStyle = {border:'1px solid silver'} // at the top of the file or just import this from other file containing styles
```

Use it in render like this:

```
 <Grid
   data={this.props.positionGridData}
   style={gridStyle}
 />
```

As I can see, you are just doing setState in **openAddNewModal** function and you are not changing positionGridData passed to Grid Component. You can use **shouldComponentUpdate** function in your Grid Component and **shallowCompare** the new props with the older one just like this:

```
import shallowEqual from 'shallowequal'

class Grid extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    !shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps)
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

**shallowEqual** will do the shallow comparison of the values. For more detail, you can go [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallowequal)